# Combined CSS file functionality

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying to reduce the http requests on my website by combining multiple CSS files. I'm copying and pasting them in the order they are right now when it all works but when I try using this giant combined CSS file certain icons aren't showing up. The problem seems to be with a font-awesome CSS file, as when I separate that out the icons show up.

I thought that multiple CSS files functioned exactly the same as if you were to combine them in order but this does not seem to be the case for me. I don't know whether maybe it's because the combined CSS file is too big (466 kb) or that I'm combining minified and normal files, I've checked that all the selectors are the exact same but it's not showing the same specific icons.

Is there something about combining CSS files that I'm missing?

Comment: The content is most likely *not* the same.

Comment: font-awesome requires the actual font file (.eot, woff, ttf ecc...). So if you were using a CDN, now you need to download all the resources and put them in your server. Anyway i suggest you to keep using a CDN, as it's more likely that the user visiting your website has already a cached version of those files

https://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font Awesome makes reference to a `fonts` directory where the font files are stored. In your combined CSS file you will need to make sure that either the fonts folder is still in the right spot relative to your CSS file or you will need to alter the path to the fonts that font awesome is using.

Below is the snippet Font Awesome uses to reference the fonts. You may need to change the `../fonts/` to `./fonts/` if your stylesheet and fonts folder are in the same directory.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Normally the CSS for font awesome is stored in a CSS folder. So the CSS tries to find fonts in  the fonts folder one level higher than the CSS.

Comment: Thankyou so much. this has been driving me crazy!

Comment: If you're using a browser with an inspector this type of thing will often show up in the console as a missing file. So if things aren't working right check the inspector and see if there are any details that point you in the right direction. Cheers!

Comment: Yea it looks like other CSS files in the combined file have paths so I'll have to figure out where to put it and change all the paths

Answer (score -1):

You can try with minifier CSS. you have to reduce the weight this way.

check link: [CSS minifier](https://cssminifier.com)